# PowerShell's Get-ChildItem on SharePoint Library

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell

I've mapped a SharePoint Online Document library to a drive letter with the intention of running the Get-ChildItem command on it generate a list of folders (minus the files).  It seems I can't map cd (change directory) in Powershell to the specific letter.

Whilst I'm looking into sorting this, I'm wondering if there is just a way so straight cd to the document library from which I can run the commands needed.  I've used Get-PSProvder to see if SharePoint is listed as a provider and it isn't, so I'm guessing it isn't, however, I'd appreciate any guidance to the contrary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just an update on this, I managed to remote into a mapped drive using the webdav protocol.  So, for instance rather than executing

cd Y:\ (the letter I'd mapped too)

Running this command worked

cd \myDomain.sharepoint.com@SSL\davWWWRoot\sites\MySite

it worked just fine.  Commands like dir and the various permutations of Get-Child worked for me.